# How do I remove the root array in a mongoose schema?

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my mongodb database when I do a get request to receive all items it comes with this response but there is an array I don't want there. Here is the response:

```
[{"_id":"598f43ab610a4b3540481615","__v":0,"data":[{"name":"Test","ip":"1","port":7777,"_id":"598f43ab610a4b3540481616","online":true}]}]
```

That First array it is in [] covering the response has no name and I don't know how to remove it.

Comment: Use `findOne`, not `find`.

Comment: @robertklep Would this still give back a list of all items in the database?

Comment: No, it would return one document, but that's basically what you're asking. You can't have a list of items without an array holding them.

Comment: @SriduttRamlall That's what the Array is giving you – a collection (list) of the documents that matched the query.

Comment: @robertklep Is there anyway possible to name that root array giving the list of items?

Comment: @SriduttRamlall array's don't have names. You can create an object that holds the array, though: `{ myArray : theArray }` (where `theArray` is the actual array that you receive from the database query)

Comment: @robertklep How would I be able to do this in a mongoose schema? I can show my schema here if you would like

Comment: @SriduttRamlall you can't, Mongoose will always return a list of results as an array. What problem are you trying to solve anyway?

Comment: @robertklep Im developing a game that has a server browser. This recieves a list of servers from that get request which is supposed to list all items from the database. I then have to use a plugin which gets a specific array by its name. But this wont work since i need to tell it what the root array is first

Comment: In that case, you need to modify the query result in the server so the GET response is in the correct format.

Comment: @robertklep Okay thanks. So I will have to change around the code in my node.js routes. Do you know how I can modify the query result. This is the code to list the servers:                                          router.get('/servers/list', function(req, res, next){
     PFServer.find({}).then(function(pfservers){
       res.send(pfservers),
       console.log('Successfully recieved a list of Servers from DB');
     });
});

Comment: `res.send({ nameOfArray : pfservers })` (where `nameOfArray` is the name that the array needs to have for the plugin)

Comment: Thank you so much @robertklep for the help, this will work. I appreciate it :)